# Generic Linq to Entities filter method that accepts filter criteria and properties to be filtered

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, linq-to-entities

I've looked into many generic linq filtering questions and their answers here in SO but none of them satisfy my needs so I thought I should create a question.

I've created many of what I call "filter provider" classes, one for each entity class in my model, to provide a simplistic search for my application. I didn't want to go into more advanced solutions like Lucene.Net because a basic filtering with matching score would suffice.

Inside each one of these provider classes there are multiple methods that will receive the filtering terms and query specific properties, returning a score for each match based on the relevance of the property. Most methods will filter multiple properties at once, but not all.

Here are two of these methods:

```
private IQueryable<Retailer> MatchHighRelevanceFields(string searchTerm, IQueryable<Retailer> retailers)
{
    var results = retailers.Where(r =>
        (r.CompanyName != null && r.CompanyName.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm))
        || (r.TradingName != null && r.TradingName.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm))
    );

    return results;
}

private IQueryable<Retailer> MatchMediumRelevanceFields(string searchTerm, IQueryable<Retailer> retailers)
{
    var results = retailers.Where(r =>
        (r.Address.Street != null && r.Address.Street.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm))
        || (r.Address.Complement != null && r.Address.Complement.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm))
    );

    return results;
}
```

These methods are replicated ad nauseum throughout each provider class and I hope I could replace them for a single method that would receive the properties to be included in the query.

Something like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Match<T>(string searchTerm, IQueryable<T> data, Expression<Func<T, string>> filterProperties)
{
    var results = **build the query for each property in filterProperties**

    return results;
}
```

But I really can't figure it out. I tried using reflection but it only worked with Linq to Objects and I need a solution for Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So to solve this problem we need a few puzzle pieces first.  The first puzzle piece is a method that can take an expression that computes a value, and then another expression that computes a new value taking the same type the first returns, and creates a new expression that represents the result of passing the result of the first function as the parameter to the second.  This allows us to `Compose` expressions:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This relies on the following tool to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

We'll also need a tool to help us `OR` two predicate expressions together:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Now that we have this we can use `Compose` on each property selector to map it from the property results to whether or not that property value is non-null and contains the search term.  We can then OR all of those predicates together to get a filter for your query:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Match<T>(
    IQueryable<T> data,
    string searchTerm,
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, string>>> filterProperties)
{
    var predicates = filterProperties.Select(selector =>
            selector.Compose(value => 
                value != null && value.Contains(searchTerm)));
    var filter = predicates.Aggregate(
        PredicateBuilder.False<T>(),
        (aggregate, next) => aggregate.Or(next));
    return data.Where(filter);
}
```

Comment: @Servy This is great. One problem I'm having though is `value.Contains(...)`. That's the OP's search logic, correct? I want to match on any word in the search term with any word in the property value. I have this in it's own method that splits the values into arrays and compares but this doesn't work in EF because it doesn't understand the method. How would I do that? Can take to chat if you want

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with expression trees but it's not as simple as you might think.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Match<T>(this IQueryable<T> data, string searchTerm,
                                         params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] filterProperties)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "source");

    Expression body = null;

    foreach (var prop in filterProperties)
    {
        // need to replace all the expressions with the one parameter (gist taken from Colin Meek blog see link on top of class)

        //prop.body should be the member expression
        var propValue =
            prop.Body.ReplaceParameters(new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>()
                {
                    {prop.Parameters[0], parameter}
                });


        // is null check
        var isNull = Expression.NotEqual(propValue, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string)));

        // create a tuple so EF will parameterize the sql call
        var searchTuple = Tuple.Create(searchTerm);
        var matchTerm = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(searchTuple), "Item1");
        // call ToUpper
        var toUpper = Expression.Call(propValue, "ToUpper", null);
        // Call contains on the ToUpper
        var contains = Expression.Call(toUpper, "Contains", null, matchTerm);
        // And not null and contains
        var and = Expression.AndAlso(isNull, contains);
        // or in any additional properties
        body = body == null ? and : Expression.OrElse(body, and);
    }

    if (body != null)
    {
        var where = Expression.Call(typeof (Queryable), "Where", new[] {typeof (T)}, data.Expression,
                                    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter));
        return data.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(where);
    }
    return data;
}

 public static Expression ReplaceParameters(this Expression exp, IDictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
{
    return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);
}
```

Now you need to have a expressionvisitor to make all the expressions use one parameter

```
//http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx
public class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly IDictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> _map;

    public ParameterRebinder(IDictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
    {
        _map = map;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (_map.ContainsKey(node))
        {
            return _map[node];
        }
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Would use it like

```
var matches = retailers.Match("7", r => r.Address.Street, x => x.Address.Complement).ToList();
```

Warning - I checked this with linq to objects using the AsQueryable but didn't run it against EF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Linq.Dynamic`](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) to build the query.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Match<T>(
    string searchTerm, 
    IQueryable<T> data, 
    params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] filterProperties) where T : class
{
    var predicates = new List<string>();
    foreach (var prop in filterProperties)
    {
        var lambda = prop.ToString();
        var columnName = lambda.Substring(lambda.IndexOf('.') + 1);
        var predicate = string.Format(
            "({0} != null && {0}.ToUpper().Contains(@0))", columnName);
        predicates.Add(predicate);
    }

    var filter = string.Join("||", predicates);
    var results = data.Where(filter, searchTerm);
    return results;
}
```

Usage.

```
var retailers = Match(
    "asd", db.Retailers, r => r.CompanyName, r => r.TradingName);

var retailers = Match(
    "asd", db.Retailers, r => r.Address.Street, r => r.Address.Complement);
```

Limitation.

The filter can only accept basic expression.

- `r => r.Name`
- `r => r.PropA.Name`
- `r => r.PropA.PropB.Name`

Comment: This is *extremely* fragile, cannot support many different types of selector expressions, and can easily have its syntax broken as a result of attempting to parse the string representation of an unknown expression.

Comment: @Servy, I built it based on OP sample code, if you can provide another example that I can test, that would be great

Comment: I did.  I posted it in my answer.

Comment: @Servy, sample usage that you said could break this method

Comment: Anything that's not *just* an accessor of a property, say, `item => "foo" + item.Property`, the use of a closure `item => someClosedOverVariable`, or the use of `EntityFunctions` `item => EntityFunctions.Left(item.Something, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Expressions like those all

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493917/Dynamic-Querying-with-LINQ-to-Entities-and-Express