# Filter IQueryable with generic lambda Expression

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, generic-programming, generic-lambda

I am trying to filter the `DateTime?` fields of my classes with a generic function. But I got the error `"The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()."`

And I dont know what is wrong.

This is my extension function:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity>? FilterDateField<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> entities, Expression<Func<TEntity, DateTime?>> dbField, DateTime dateField)
{
    var t1 = entities.Where(e=>dbField.Compile().Invoke(e).HasValue && dbField.Compile().Invoke(e)== dateField);

    return t1;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? An example of the data you are trying to filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer from another question here: [Generic Linq to Entities filter method that accepts filter criteria and properties to be filtered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508595/generic-linq-to-entities-filter-method-that-accepts-filter-criteria-and-properti)

It was just add this code in the class who holds the `FilterDateField` function

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>  Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first, Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}

public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression, Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

And them use de Compose like this:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity>? FilterDateField<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> entities, Expression<Func<TEntity, DateTime?>> dbField, DateTime dateField)
{
    var dateHasValue = dbField.Compose(value => value.HasValue);
    var t1 = entities.Where(dateHasValue);

    return t1;
}
```